# Spring MVC+Hibernate deployment error : expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC + Hibernate world. I have developed a small application with Java annotation based configuration. I am receiving following error at deployment stage:

FAIL - Deployed application at context path /NioERPJ but context failed to start

Apache Tomcat Log displays following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.nej.users.service.MyUserDetailsService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}.

My UserController.Java file is below:

```
package com.nej.controller;

import java.util.Map;
import com.nej.users.model.User;;
import com.nej.users.service.MyUserDetailsService;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
/**
 *
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/admin/usermgmt"})
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myuserdetailsservice;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/listUsers","/" })
    public String listUsers(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("user", new User());
        map.put("userList", myuserdetailsservice.listUsers());
        return "/admin/usermgmt";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/get/{username}")
    public String getUser(@PathVariable String username, Map<String, Object> map) {
        User user = myuserdetailsservice.getUser(username);
        map.put("user", user);
        return "/admin/useraddedit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,BindingResult result) {
        myuserdetailsservice.saveUser(user);

    /*
    * Note that there is no slash "/" right after
    "redirect:"
    * So, it redirects to the path relative to the current
    path
    */
    return "redirect:admin/usermgmt";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{username}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        myuserdetailsservice.deleteUser(username);
    /*
    * redirects to the path relative to the current path
    */
    // return "redirect:../listBooks";
    /*
    * Note that there is the slash "/" right after
    "redirect:"
    * So, it redirects to the path relative to the project
    root path
    */
    return "redirect:/admin/usermgmt";
}
}
```

However, if I remove the Autowired from the

```
`@Autowired`
`private MyUserDetailsService myuserdetailsservice;`
```

line, then application deploys successfully, but when the application hits the

```
`map.put("userList", myuserdetailsservice.listUsers()); `
```

line, it displays null pointer exception. Please help me with the removal of the error.

My MyUserDetailService.java file is as below:

```
package com.nej.users.service;

/**
 *
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.nej.users.dao.UserDao;
import com.nej.users.model.UserRole;

@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    //get user from the database, via Hibernate
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        com.nej.users.model.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }
// Converts com.mkyong.users.model.User user to
// org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
    private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.nej.users.model.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
        user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }
    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
// Build user's authorities
        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
        return Result;
    }


    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(com.nej.users.model.User user) {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional( readOnly = true)
    public List<com.nej.users.model.User> listUsers() {
        return userDao.listUsers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteUser(String username) {
        userDao.deleteUser(username);
    }

    @Transactional( readOnly = true)
    public com.nej.users.model.User getUser(String username) {
        return userDao.findByUserName(username);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your quick and precise response, as suggested I have added the component scan for the package com.nej.users.service in the configuration file as shown below, but result is the same, I am still receiving the same error.

```
package com.nej.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 *
 */
@Configuration  
@EnableWebMvc  
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.nej.controller", "com.nej.users.service"})
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

        @Override  
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/mytheme/");  
        }

}
```

Please help me in resolving the error.

I have changed the @Autowired annotation to @Autowired(required=false) in the UserController.java

```
@Autowired(required=false)
private MyUserDetailsService myuserdetailsservice;
```

then application is deploying successfully, however, still I am getting the Null Pointer Assignment when hitting the

map.put("userList", myuserdetailsservice.listUsers());

line. Now, can we narrow down at the cause of the error? Pl. suggest.

Comment: The symptoms say : the bean is not wired by spring. As your configuration looks correct, I suppose the problem to be in Spring bootstrapping. Do you use a `web.xml` file or a `WebApplicationInitializer` and what do they contain ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `MyUserDetailsService` is not picked up by Spring. You need to add the `com.nej.users.service` to your component scan. If you use Java configuration you add it using annotation:

```
@ComponentScan("com.nej.users.service")
```

or if you use XML configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nej.users.service"/>
```

---

The `NullPointerException` that you experience when you remove the `@Autowired` annotation is easy to understand. Since the declared `MyUserDetailsService myuserdetailsservice` field will be `null` since is never initialized. Consequently, the attempt to call `myuserdetailsservice.listUsers()` will throw a NPE.

Comment: I have implemented the suggestion, however, I am still receiving the same error, please see the configuration file which I have uploaded.

Comment: Please suggest some alternative, as I am still not able to resolve the error.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have any more suggestions. It seems like you have  the correct configuration. Otherwise, it is just the usual suspects, double check for spelling errors (which I am sure that you already have), make sure that your configuration file is included (if your project has more than the one config), recompile the entire project (especially important if the `MyUserDetailsService`, `UserController` and `WebAppConfig` are in different sub-projects, etc.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I will recheck again

Comment: I have made @Autowired(required=false) now project is deployed successfully, however, I am still receiving NPE at the same line. Can this help in narrowing down to the error?

Comment: The problem is the same as before, Spring is unable to find the  `MyUserDetailsService` bean. Configuring the autowiring does not change anything, you just postpone the error and changing the symptoms from a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` to a NPE (because the declared field will remain `null`). You must figure out why Spring fails to locate and create your bean. Side note, I prefer keeping the autowiring required because of its "fail fast" approach, i.e. a potential NSBDE during startup. Otherwise, depending on the application, it may take a very long time before the error is discovered.